# For loop JQuery outputs the same ID 4 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some trouble with my `for()` loop in JQuery.

I have the following code:

```
for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(roster).length; i++) {
     fillMatchRoster(getUserEligible(roster[i].user_id), findUser(roster[i].user_id), findGamertag(roster[i].user_id));

     // Shows 4 different ID's
     alert(roster[i].user_id);

     // Outputs the same ID 4 times
     if(findGamertag(roster[i].user_id) != "") {
           $('.match_create_roster_playing').html("<input type='checkbox' value='" + roster[i].user_id + "'>");
     }
}
```

It should output 4 different ID's as checkbox values but instead I see 4 the same.

HTML output:

[image: HTML output]

UPDATE:

`findGamertag()`:

```
function findGamertag(id) {
    var user = "";

    $.ajax({ 

        url: '/data/user_info.php',
        data: {user: id},
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(json) {

            user = json.gamertag;

        },
        error: function(ts) {
            console.log("Error: " + ts.responseText);
        }
    });

    return user;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `findGamertag` makes an ajax call?

Comment: @freedomn-m That is correct

Comment: can try the same code by changing the if statement  roster !=[]

Comment: Does line 9 override all `$('.match_create_roster_playing')`, doesn't it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: @MohamedNizar I now only see 1 checkbox

Comment: @freedomn-m but that won't make it run 4 times right?

Comment: are you sure that 'findGamertag' return correct data?

Comment: @MohamedNizar UPDATE: just tested the `roster != []` again and I now have the same output again. So, 4 of the same ID's

Comment: Please include (the basic parts of) the code for `findGamertag`

Comment: @freedomn-m Just added it

Comment: @Chris What do you get when you output `i` inside `findGamertag(roster[i].user_id) != "")` conditional block.

Comment: @Samundra This question is resolved. Thanks for the help though

Comment: While your selector issue solves your immediate problem, your `if`will be your next issue because the line `user=json.gamertag` occurs *after* you have returned from the function.  (add an alert there or a console.log there and inside the if).   Link here with your next question when you get to that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can bet that value 6 is the last user's id. That happens, cause **you override the HTML of every `td` element with given class name**. Line 9 literally replaces inner html on every iteration.

[By adding `.eq`](https://jsfiddle.net/p7yx1e60/2/) it seems like the result is correct.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Could you explain what it does?

Comment: By calling `$('.match_create_roster_playing')` you get all elements with that class. Followed by `html()` **you replace every element's inner HTML** with new values every iteration. Adding `.eq` helps, cause on each iteration I take first row, and update it's html, then second row and so on.

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't know about that one! Thanks a lot!